# Intersection of a curve with its asymptote

Tags: calculus, algebraic-geometry

Consider the folium of Descartes $x^3+y^3=3axy $ and its asymptote $x+y+a=0$. By Bezout's theorem they should intersect thrice; two of which are clearly at infinity by the graph. What is the third point?

Comment: There is only one point at infinity on the line $x + y + a = 0.$ That gives you _one_ obvious intersection. It happens to be a triple root, as explained below.

Answer (score 1):

Homogenize, then plug in $y=-x-az$ to the first equation and simplify: 
$$x^3-(x+az)^3=-3axz(x+az)$$ 
$$x^3-(x^3+3ax^2z+3a^2xz^2+a^3z^3) = -3ax^2z - 3a^2xz^2$$ 
$$ 3ax^2z+3a^2xz^2+a^3z^3 = 3ax^2z + 3a^2xz^2$$ 
$$ a^3z^3 = 0$$

So all 3 solutions are actually at infinity, assuming $a\neq 0$.

Comment: Why is $y=-x-az $?

Comment: We work in $\Bbb P^2$ to apply Bezout's theorem, so we need to turn the equation $x+y+a=0$ on the patch $z\neq 0$ into a homogeneous equation valid everywhere in $\Bbb P^2$. The way to do this is homogenizing it, which gives us $x+y+az=0$.